# From a choice of $5$ breads, $10$ biscuits, and $6$ types of candies, find the number of ways of selecting at most one of each

Tags: combinatorics

> From a choice of $5$ breads, $10$ biscuits, and $6$ types of candies, find the number of ways to select at most $1$ of each.

I was recently introduced to combinatorics. There is a confusion for me with introducing at most $1$ of them in the conditions. Can anyone explain me about this?

Comment: For e.g. bread there are $6$ choices. This because there are $5$ distinct breads that can be chosen and next to that you can also choose no bread at all.

Comment: I edited to remove excessive punctuation. One question mark is always enough.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

*At most 1* means either 0 or 1. So you are asked how many ways are there to select 0 or 1 of each groups. By way of example, there are 10 biscuits, so you can select 0 biscuits or 1 of the 10 given, for 11 total choices.

You have 3 classes (breads, biscuits and candies), what are the number of ways for each type? For all of them together?

Comment: but arent the biscuits indistinguishable?? i mean i thought the number of ways to select 1 biscuit out of 10 is 1. Is that wrong??

Comment: Based on the question, it wouldn't really make sense to assume that the biscuits were indistinguishable since otherwise, you don't need to know that there are 10 biscuits, just that there are some in general. Unless this is some sort of purposefully confusing trick question, it's just more natural to assume that they're distinct.